# How to call Oracle procedure have Userdefined "Type" IN parameters using jdbc in java

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I have created below user defined TYPE in oracle. I am using this TYPE in procedure as IN parameter. How to call the procedure using Jdbc CallableStatement.

create or replace TYPE "VARCHAR_TAB"
is
table of varchar2(500);

My Procedure is:

procedure delete_album_metadata
  (
   p_catalog_tab in varchar_tab
  );

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the setPlsqlIndexTable binder method which is defined in oracle.jdbc.OraclePreparedStatement.

Here is a pointer to the JavaDoc:

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JAJDB/oracle/jdbc/OraclePreparedStatement.html#setPlsqlIndexTable_int__java_lang_Object__int__int__int__int_

Comment: Um, no.  Your link is for index-by tables, also known as PL/SQL associative arrays.  The questioner's table type is a nested table type.